# i have got a validation problem!

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

i want to validate the control myself. So i put a label and a condition when i press the button.

```
 protected void sendButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (QuestionDetailsTextBox2.Text.Length > 5000)
    {
        QuestionDetailsTextBox2.Text = "You cant enter more than 5000 characters";
    }
    else if(QuestionTextBox1.Text.Length > 100)
    {
        QuestionDetailsTextBox2.Text = "You cant enter more than 100 characters";
    }
    else if (checkValidation())
    {

        QuestionTextBox1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("AnswerQuestion.aspx");
    }
}
```

i added a regular expression validater. But i also did this:

```
  protected void topicDropDownMenu_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Clear();

    string[] chosenItem = topic[topicDropDownMenu.SelectedItem.Value];

    foreach (string item in chosenItem)
    {
        SubTopicDropDownList.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Again, i need to press the button twice so that it would redirect me :(... ajax is still necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an immediate response you will have to move your validation logic to the client.  This usually means you write your validation logic in javascript and call it from the client side click event of the button or change event of the textbox before processing the postback events.

Doing your checks in code behind requires a round trip to the server.  Whether you do it this way and postback the full page or use ajax and do a partial postback, there is a delay while the data is sent to the server and the client waits for a response.  How big of a delay depends on how much data needs to be transferred and network conditions.  This is why ajax is generally faster, it gets to send smaller batches of data.

However you handle the client side validation, it is generally considered a best practice to repeat the validation logic in the code behind.  This is to catch any instances where a user has client side scripting disabled.

Comment: i guess the answer is to use ajax

Comment: @Dmitry - If all you are after is validating the length of the users input, you could try a regex validator.  Something along the lines of ".{20,100}" for your regex should get you close to what it looks like you are after.

Comment: i found regular expression that works. Are the validaters based on ajax.. they dont send info back, do they? or can i achieve the effect they achieve by using their functions or using the page events?

Comment: @Dmitry - If memory serves the standard validators perform client side checks with a server side recheck as their normal behavior. There are properties on the validators that let you adjust this behavior. There are ajax variants of the validators as well but I have not used them enough to notice how exactly they behave, I would assume it is similar. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx gives links to the various validation articles.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Partial Page Update](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax).

You can use AJAX and [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx).

Comment: is it my only hope? is there another way to see if the question was too short??

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd: It is recommended to use CustomValidator. However, what are you asking for is to make it look as if it was a client side processing. You need Partial PostBack. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks arkam. i think i will abandon, that validation for now, and may be will come back to it later on..

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd: I'll be here if you needed me :)

Comment: okay. i used two validations. There is no lag now. I can achieve the effects of the validaters only with ajax or client side code? There is no other way!!

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd: As far as I know, not yet !!